# How to make users to download files in Dropbox with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, dropbox

I'm now trying to make a function that allows users to access to the link of the file to download.

The native link is https://www.dropbox.com/home/Apps/ringle_records?preview=lesson_id_11%3Auser_id_5.mp3 but, it is only accessible by admin ( for sure ). If I have a user who is eligible to know this link, then I would love to allow this user to click some button to download the file.

I am kind of bogged down when it comes to implementation. Because if I use the below code, it seems it stores data into the server.

```
def self.dropbox_download
    contents, metadata = Drop_client.get_file_and_metadata('/lesson_id_12:user_id_7.mp3.mp3')
    begin
      File.open('filename.mp3', 'wb') do |file|
        file.write(contents)
      end
    rescue
    end
  end
```

I want to make user to click something and the "mp3" file will be downloaded, but I don't think the above code works in this way.

Please shoot any opinion! I'm looking forward to seeing!

Best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only need to allow other users to download this specific file (or some specific set of files), the easiest way is to just get a shared link to the relevant file(s):

https://www.dropbox.com/help/167

You can modify these shared links for different behaviors, e.g., for file downloads, as shown here:

https://www.dropbox.com/help/201

If you do need to get these links programmatically, you can use the `shares` method:

https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-ruby/api-docs/v1.6.4/DropboxClient.html#method-i-shares

You can then give the shared link to the user, e.g., as a link on a web page, or in an email, etc.

Comment: It works! I'm going to take the third option you put here. Whenever user query, I reload the url link for the user! (: THanks!